# Collection<Interface> name = null;

Tags: java, collections, interface

What exactly does it mean when you have a Collection< name of interface> variable = null;

What kind of variable is this?

I thought collection itself was an interface .

Rephrased Question:

Suppose you have an interface.

```
public interface stack
{
String push();

String pop();

}
```

and are given

```
Collection<stack> myname = null ;
```

in some class

how would you populate myname?

Comment: What would it mean if you had `Collection<name of class>`? It means the exact same thing.

Comment: Please learne `Generics`, it is hard to describe it here "on the fly"
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/

Comment: not even generics, first read about references: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is Polymorphism, and yes Collection is an interface. It describes the contract that every client of a Collection can expect, and that every implementation of a Collection must honour. At some point the variable will have to point to an actual implementation, such as ArrayList, that conforms to the contract.

Collection also has another form of Polymorphism in the form of Generics. So the collection can contain objects of a particular type that will be determined when the Collection is declared. The type could itself be an interface,  but the underlying members of the Collection will have to be concrete implementations of the type declared

For example:

```
// ArrayList honours the contract of Collection
// All members must be a String
Collection<String> var = new ArrayList<String>();

// HashSet honours the contract of Collection
// All members must be one of the implementing classes of Principal
Collection<Prinicpal> users = new HashSet<Principal>();
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case stack would be the type of the elements in the collection,
you could populate it with something like this:

```
Collection<stack> myName = new ArrayList<stack>();
myName.add(new stackImpl());
```

Being stackImpl a class implementing stack and ArrayList a class implementing Collection.

Comment: Thanks, I had a Job interview Question and I did exactly this, but I'm wondering what does this accomplish why would you have a collection of interfaces?

Comment: The reason is to be able to hold diffrent types of instances with a common interface. For example you could put in a Collection<Comparable> many types of instances, like String or Integer, then, when you iterate the collection, you could put the iterated element in a Comparable variable and call the compare method on each instance. So you are less tied to the implementation you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<stack> myname` denotes a collection of objects that are from a class that implements the interface `stack`. In order to create and fill something like this:

```
Collection<stack> myname = new ArrayList<stack>();
myname.add(new MyStack());


// Where
class MyStack implements stack { ... }
```

Is there any caveat hidden in the question? I guess not.